# Async/Await Function inside Object iteration and Callback

Tags: javascript, object, async-await, promise, callback

My Object is like below

```
let obj = [
  {
    "id": "hlahl2c",
    "name": "Media(video) 1",
    "type": "video",
    "placement": {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "width": 617.2537313432834,
      "height": 558.7462686567162,
      "rotation": 0,
      "scaleX": 1,
      "scaleY": 1
    },
    "timeFrame": {
      "start": 0,
      "end": 2001.9999999999998
    },
    "properties": {
      "elementId": "video-hlahl2c",
      "src": "blob:http://localhost:3000/68d041d2-0eef-4bf1-ae3b-fd25af555fcd",
      "effect": {
        "type": "none"
      },
      "imageObject": {
        "type": "coverVideo",
        "version": "5.3.0",
        "originX": "left",
        "originY": "top",
        "left": 0,
        "top": 0,
        "width": 617.25,
        "height": 558.75,
        "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)",
        "stroke": null,
        "strokeWidth": 0,
        "strokeDashArray": null,
        "strokeLineCap": "butt",
        "strokeDashOffset": 0,
        "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
        "strokeUniform": false,
        "strokeMiterLimit": 4,
        "scaleX": 1,
        "scaleY": 1,
        "angle": 0,
        "flipX": false,
        "flipY": false,
        "opacity": 1,
        "shadow": null,
        "visible": true,
        "backgroundColor": "",
        "fillRule": "nonzero",
        "paintFirst": "fill",
        "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
        "skewX": 0,
        "skewY": 0,
        "cropX": 0,
        "cropY": 0,
        "src": "blob:http://localhost:3000/68d041d2-0eef-4bf1-ae3b-fd25af555fcd",
        "crossOrigin": null,
        "filters": []
      }
    },
    "fabricObject": {
      "type": "coverVideo",
      "version": "5.3.0",
      "originX": "left",
      "originY": "top",
      "left": 0,
      "top": 0,
      "width": 617.25,
      "height": 558.75,
      "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)",
      "stroke": null,
      "strokeWidth": 0,
      "strokeDashArray": null,
      "strokeLineCap": "butt",
      "strokeDashOffset": 0,
      "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
      "strokeUniform": false,
      "strokeMiterLimit": 4,
      "scaleX": 1,
      "scaleY": 1,
      "angle": 0,
      "flipX": false,
      "flipY": false,
      "opacity": 1,
      "shadow": null,
      "visible": true,
      "backgroundColor": "",
      "fillRule": "nonzero",
      "paintFirst": "fill",
      "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
      "skewX": 0,
      "skewY": 0,
      "cropX": 0,
      "cropY": 0,
      "src": "blob:http://localhost:3000/68d041d2-0eef-4bf1-ae3b-fd25af555fcd",
      "crossOrigin": null,
      "filters": []
    }
  }
]
```

As you can see src is in bloburl  , so before I send to server  I like to convert all sources to base64 strng  , to do that I need a async/await function to convert that src from blob url to base64.

First  I used a function to deepsearch all src key and then planed to use a callback functon to convert that bloburl  , but that callback functon need to be async/await , but function is not working as expected, To do deepsearch I have used following functon

```
const deepReplace = (obj, keyName, replacer) => {
    for (const key in obj) {
        if (key === keyName) {
            obj[key] = replacer(obj[key]);
        } else if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
            (obj[key] ).forEach(member => deepReplace(member, keyName, replacer));
        } else if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            deepReplace(obj[key], keyName, replacer);
        }
    }
};
```

For callback this is the following dummy function

```
replace_value_func=(value)=>{
  return value+" someword appended"
}
```

While I am calling `deepReplace(obj,'src',replace_value_func)` , as long replace_value_func is synchronously everything is woring as expected  , but  I need to use replace_value_func asynchronously  because through that function   I need to convert bloburl to base64 , but while I am usiing async replace_value_func it's just returning empty object . HOW  I CAN USE async function as a callback function inside loop?

Search and Replace Nested Object Value Based on Key using Async function

While I am using Async/Await I am using following

```
const deepReplace = async(obj, keyName, replacer) => {
    for (const key in obj) {
        if (key === keyName) {
            obj[key] = await replacer(obj[key]);
        } else if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
            (obj[key] ).forEach(member => deepReplace(member, keyName, replacer));
        } else if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            deepReplace(obj[key], keyName, replacer);
        }
    }
};

replace_value_func_with_promise = (value)=>{
  return new Promise(resolve => {
     res="something"+value
   resolve(res)
    });      
}

deepReplace(Obj,'src',replace_value_func_with_promise)
```

But Above code is not working

Comment: Stop using `.forEach()`. Javascript now has a much better syntax for array iteration: `for .. of`

Comment: Currently change to  else if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
          for  (const member of (obj[key])) {
          deepReplace(member, keyName);
          } the forEach portion and having the same result ,  code just ignoring await portion  and putting original value rather than await

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare `deepReplace` as an async function.
2. Don't use `.forEach` in an async function without special precautions. Use a standard `for` , `for...of` or `for.. in` (if applicable) loop instead.
3. `await` potentially asynchonous results
4. Call `deepReplacer` prefixed with `await`, or use `.then` and `.catch` clauses on the returned promise in synchonous calling code.

Note you can never obtain the result of  asynchronous operations immediately upon return from an `async` function - they return a promise of a value, not a value obtained sometime later.

Comment: Plese do not accept or vote on this answer - it's too long for a comment.  The post will likely be nomintated as a duplicate shortly.

Comment: I have updated the OP, as you can see for async/await I have used async and await but that code was not working

Comment: 1. `await` will resolve primitive values as the primitive value. Refer to `await` documentation. Hence `replace_value_func_with_promise` should not be needed. 2. recursive calls to `deepReplacer` from within `deepReplacer` need `await` before them. 3. `deepReplacer` still contains a `.forEach` loop in the post which calls argument functions in a **synchronous** loop with no waiting.  Do not use `forEach`. 4. Avoid using the phrase "Doesn't work" on SO. :-)